# VBA Create a macro that creates new macros

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that inserts *Image* controls on a form.
When these controls are clicked the user is asked to select an image file using the `GetOpenFileName` dialog box.  The selected image is loaded into the control and the file path is added to column `B` on `Sheet2`.
When the *Image* control is clicked again the selected image is loaded to an *Image* control on a second form and displayed.

How do I add or attach the required code to each image control so the *Click* events will work?

The code I have so far is below:

```
Sub macroA1()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set miesto = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2")
strfilename = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value
If strfilename = "" Then
strfilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Tiff     Files(*.tif;*.tiff),*.tif;*.tiff,JPEG Files (*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.jfif;*.jpe),*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.jfif;*.jpe,Bitmap Files(*.bmp),*.bmp", FilterIndex:=2, Title:="Select a File", MultiSelect:=False)
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value = strfilename
ElseIf strfilename = "False" Then
strfilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Tiff Files(*.tif;*.tiff),*.tif;*.tiff,JPEG Files (*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.jfif;*.jpe),*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.jfif;*.jpe,Bitmap Files(*.bmp),*.bmp", FilterIndex:=2, Title:="Select a File", MultiSelect:=False)
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value = strfilename
Else
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value = strfilename
End If

On Error Resume Next
UserForm1.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(strfilename)

If strfilename = "False" Then
MsgBox "File Not Selected!"
Exit Sub
Else
End If

UserForm1.Image1.PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeStretch
UserForm1.Show

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to the board.  Could you have a read of [MCVE] please.  At the moment, taking the information you've given into account, the best answer you'll get is probably "Yes, but why would you when you could get all the shapes to reference the same macro?"

Comment: I did it this way because these macros are taking pictures from special paths (strfilename) to UserForm and after clicking on the shape shows them. Each shape is connected to unique sub. In this macro will the ranges change (because in these ranges are the paths of pictures that the macro is loading.

Comment: I was about to start on my answer, but has been ordained that the question doesn't meet standard....  From what I can tell you have a number of image controls on a form that are created at run-time.  When one of these controls is clicked you want the user to navigate to a picture which is then loaded into the control?  If this is correct I'll have a go at rewording your question.

Comment: Yes something like that but not to navigate the user but show the picture. But this part is working it shows the pictures but i have to write the macro for each one shape.I edited the question to create it more understandable.

Comment: I've reworded the question to hopefully reflect what you're after.  I can't see in your code where you're adding controls, but that seems to be what you're trying to do?  _Feel free to roll-back the edit if I've got it wrong._

Comment: The first part is ok but i can add and attach existing code but if i inser 200 shapes i need to write the same code in vba 200 times because the code is loading path from specified range on sheet2 and i wanted to know is is possible to write this macros automaticly after adding new shape (I have a button that insert shape an connect it wit maco A & i by selection OnAction.

Comment: I don't think you'll need to add the code 200 times - each shape can use the same piece of code which will look up the required file path from the sheet or add a new image path to the sheet as required.  Just waiting on one more person to reopen the question....

Comment: DRY doesn't mean writing code that will automatically repeat the code for you. @DarrenBartrup-Cook is almost certainly correct that you can write the code just once in one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each *Image* control on your *userform* will need a click event.  This single event is stored within a *class* module and attached to each *Image* control on the form.

- Insert a class module, name it `clsLoadImage` and add the code below to it.

---

```
Public WithEvents Img As MSForms.Image 'Place at very top of module (after Option Explicit though).

Private Sub Img_Click()

    Dim FullPath As String

    With Img
        'Only load the picture if the control is empty.
        If .Picture Is Nothing Then

            'Get the file path for the image.
            FullPath = Application.GetOpenFilename

            If Len(Dir(FullPath)) = 0 Then
                MsgBox "No file find.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical
            Else
                .Tag = FullPath 'The Tag property can store extra info such as a text string.

                'Store the path in last row of Sheet2 column B.
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = FullPath

                .Picture = LoadPicture(FullPath)
                .PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeStretch
                .Parent.Repaint
            End If
        Else

            'If the image control isn't empty load the image
            'into UserForm2 using the file path stored in
            'the Tag property.

            Load UserForm2
            With UserForm2
                With .Image1
                    .Picture = LoadPicture(Img.Tag)
                    .PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeStretch
                    .Parent.Repaint
                End With
                .Show
            End With

        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

- Next add a `UserForm` to the project.  In the sample code I have left it named as `UserForm1`. Make the `Height` at at least 340 and fairly wide.
- Add a CommandButton near the top and an Image control near the bottom (I put the `Top` at 218 for the image control).
  These controls probably won't be included in your final solution but give different options depending on your requirements.
- Add the below code to `UserForm1`.
  This code will fire when you open the form.

  - The top part of the code will attach the `Click` event to any existing *Image* controls - such as the one that's placed near the bottom.
  - The bottom part of the code will create an *Image* control for each file path listed in `Sheet2` column `B` and attach the `Click` event to it.
    Note:  `Top` is set as 134 placing them in the middle area of the form.

---

```
Public ImageControls As New Collection 'Place at very top of module (after Option Explicit though).

'Could execute when the form opens.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    'Relies on image controls added at design time.
    'Attaches the click event to each image control.

    Dim Ctrl As Control
    Set ImageControls = New Collection
    Dim ImgEvent As clsLoadImage

    For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(Ctrl) = "Image" Then
            Set ImgEvent = New clsLoadImage
            Set ImgEvent.Img = Ctrl
            ImageControls.Add ImgEvent
        End If
    Next Ctrl

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    'Creates an image control for each file path
    'in Sheet2 column B, loads the picture,
    'stores the path in the tag property,
    'attaches the click event.

    Dim x As Long
    Dim tmpCtrl As Control

    For x = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

        'Add the control, name it and position it.
        Set tmpCtrl = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Image.1", "AddedInLoop_Image_" & x)
        With tmpCtrl
            .Left = .Width * (x - 2)
            .Top = 134
            .Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, 2))
            .PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeStretch
            .Tag = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, 2)
        End With

        'Attach the Click event to the control.
        Set ImgEvent = New clsLoadImage
        Set ImgEvent.Img = tmpCtrl
        ImageControls.Add ImgEvent

    Next x
    Me.Repaint

End Sub
```

- Add this code to `UserForm1` as well to deal with the CommandButton that you added.
  This will add an *Image* control each time you press the button.
  Note - `Top` is set at 40 so they'll appear near the top of the form.

---

```
'Creates an image control and attaches
'a Click event to the control.
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim CtrlCount As Long
    Dim Ctrl As Control
    Dim tmpCtrl As Control
    Dim ImgEvent As clsLoadImage

    'Count the Image controls so each
    'new control has a unique name.
    CtrlCount = 1
    For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
        'NB: The InStr command is only needed so the controls
        '    added in the Initalise event aren't counted.
        If TypeName(Ctrl) = "Image" And InStr(Ctrl.Name, "BtnClck_Image_") > 0 Then
            CtrlCount = CtrlCount + 1
        End If
    Next Ctrl

    'Add the control, name it and position it.
    Set tmpCtrl = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Image.1", "BtnClck_Image_" & CtrlCount)
    With tmpCtrl
        .Left = .Width * (CtrlCount - 1)
        .Top = 40
    End With

    'Attach the Click event to the control.
    Set ImgEvent = New clsLoadImage
    Set ImgEvent.Img = tmpCtrl
    ImageControls.Add ImgEvent

End Sub
```

Finally, add a second `UserForm` and add a single *Image* control named `Image1` filling the form.  I have left the form named as `UserForm2`.

**To use:**

- Open `UserForm1`.

  - An *Image* control will be created for each full file path & name listed in column `B` of `Sheet2`. It will display the picture from the file path.
  - Pressing the button will create a blank *Image* control.
  - Clicking a blank *Image* control will open a dialog box asking you to select a file.  The selected file will be loaded into the control and the file path added to column `B` on `Sheet2`.
  - Clicking an *Image* control that contains a picture will open `UserForm2` with the image loaded into the *Image* control on that form.